# How to pass a variable from onItemClick to some java class

Tags: android

I need to get the variable "position" from the `OnClickListener`'s `onItemClick`.

```
gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        { //Actions based on user's click }
```

This "position" will be used in the another class.
I have tried the `SharedPreferences` way but it says that
`The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){})`

In need of some help.

Comment: is it plain java class or another activity

Comment: "This "position" will be used in the another class." means in Activity??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you said, I think you are using `PreferenceManager` like

```
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // This statement gives an error.
            // here "this" represents an instance of OnItemClickListener (Anonymous inner class)
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            // but You need an instance of Context. So you can refer Activity here
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Gopal! I didn't use this solution but I was making this mistake .

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to share the position to another class You will Store the Position in in another variable..

**STATIC VARIABLE AND USE THIS VARIABLE IN THE ANOTHER CLASS**

```
     gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
       ActivityName.VariableName = position;
    }
```

You can use this variable at any where in the program...

And then you can send the Context like this...

```
  getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivityName.this);
  (or)      
  getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

All the best....

Answer (score 0):

To use `SharedPreferences`, make sure that the context you are passing is not the `OnItemClickListener()`'s.

You are on the right track with trying to save "position" for its use in another `class` or `Activity`. Passing the `context` of an `Activity` can help you to use `SharedPreferences`.

If its from another `class` which is not an `activity`, you can use a `constructor` to pass the `context` of any `activity` to that `class`.

Try to implement functions like these, it helps reduce code and implement re-usability too:

```
/** 
 * Used to save data in preferences
 * @param context
 * @param key
 * @param value
 */
public static void saveDataToPreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Your package name",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

/** 
 * Used to retrieve data from preferences
 * @param context
 * @param key
 * @return
 */
public static String getDataFromPreferences(Context context, String key) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Your package name",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getString(key, "default value");
}
```

I use that for `SharedPreferences`, quite effective. You can pass the position value and a constant string eg. "position" to save and retrieve the same. I used `String` as a generic datatype, you can either define it depending on your requirement  Eg.

```
saveDataToPreferences(context, "position", ""+1);



position = getDataFromPreferences(context, "position");  
//if nothing is saved, it will return what you have specified as the default value
```